# Commit change/create tag in TFS 2015 as part of build process using GIT

Tags: git, msbuild, tfs-2015, msbuild-task

I have a custom msbuild script in place to update a versions file and also to create a tag of the source code of a web app in a series of build steps.

These all run fine from my local machine and the versions file & tag can be pushed to the remote TFS server using my own credentials from the working directory.

I now want to run this same build script from within TFS server itself when it kicks off a scheduled overnight build & to push the changes to the server (the server being itself).  Googling suggests this isn't easy or possible to do out of the box with TFS?

Can anyone shed light on this for me?
Apologies if this has been asked already but i haven't come across a post yet.

Comment: The simplest solution is adding an [Exec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) task to your script, provided there's workspace already cloned and the build service running with a prileged user account. Something like `<Exec Command="git push ..." />`

Comment: Thanks KMoraz, that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by [KMoraz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147211/kmoraz) worked for me.